# Ubuntu 14.04 fails to boot after updates are installed

Tags: boot, updates, thinkpad

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on my new Lenovo Thinkpad T450s.

It worked for some 3 weeks, I could also install updates without problems.
But 10 days ago, after installing updates, Ubuntu failed to boot. The screen only became purple, then black.
I tried reinstallation (without causing data loss) and again it worked as long as I didn't install updates. So far the problem has occurred twice, i. e. I did the reinstallation twice and installing updates then caused the same problem.
Can anyone please give me advice what to do next? N. B. I'm new to Ubuntu and the opposite of a geek, so please be gentle and try to explain things in a way understandable to non-geeks :-) Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Trying the `nomodset` option from the above link should work, I guess. What's your graphics card?

Comment: I think my graphics card is Intel HD Graphics 5500.

Comment: Reading through the above links (thanks for posting them) I get the impression that these focus on installation problems or on copying data from a system that doesn't boot. However, booting Ubuntu from a CD as well as reinstallation did work in my case, and I didn't lose any data (also could copy them when I booted from the CD). After reinstallation, the system boots as long as I don't install updates, but when I do the problem reappears ...
Or did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Were you running updates through Ubuntu's "Software Updater"?  Try running "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" from the command-line instead.  I think I had similar issues after a recent update, which I suspect are due to the Software Updater hiding some important dpkg-reconfigure prompts for grub.

Comment: Yes, and meanwhile I found out that the kernel updates must be the problem. Currently I can install updates via Software Updater without causing problems as long as I uncheck the kernel updates.
Thanks for your answer, I'll see if your proposal works.